# Persisted Computed Column to calculate area?

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns, persisted-column

I have a table (rugs) that has columns for length and width (both 2 place decimals).

I'm trying to create a computed column named area which simply multiplies the length by width to generate the area but hitting syntax errors when running the query.

My attempted code using mySQL was as follows:

```
alter table `rugs` add `area` as (`length` * `width`) PERSISTED
```

But it's not liking the syntax, getting a #1064 error

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Please add to the question the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the syntax is:

```
alter table rug add area generated always as (length * width) stored;
```

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) explains the syntax.

Your syntax is more appropriate for SQL Server.

Comment: @RyanMalone . . . Generated columns were introduced in MySQL 5.7.???.  Your version may not support them.

Comment: @RyanMalone . . . Generated columns were introduced in MySQL 5.7.???.  Your version may not support them.