# find data missing on monthly base

Tags: mysql, search, find, where-clause

With this data table "table":

[image]

and a table "ID" of well known newID value (1,2,3)

[image]

I would like to find all the months in which some newID value are missing. The result should only include months that that have at least 1 `newId`.

This is the expected result for the data listed above:

[image]

How can I achieve this task ?

Table Schema: (fiddle) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72af42

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ID`(
    Id int unsigned not null primary key
);
INSERT INTO `ID` (Id) VALUES (1),(2),(3);

CREATE TABLE `table`(
    recId int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    Data DateTime not null,
    newID int not null
);

INSERT INTO `table` (`Data`,`newID`) VALUES
('2017-12-06',1),
('2017-12-06',3),
('2017-11-16',1),
('2017-11-16',2),
('2017-11-16',3),
('2017-10-05',2),
('2017-10-05',3),
('2017-10-03',2),
('2017-10-03',3),
('2017-08-16',1),
('2017-08-16',2),
('2017-08-16',3),
('2017-05-05',1),
('2017-05-05',2),
('2017-05-05',3);
```

Comment: `table` and `ID` are tables. You want to get the month-year from `table.Data` where `table.newID` does not exist in `ID.newID`. Is that correct? If so, your example result doesn't follow those conditions.

Comment: no more precisely I would like to know for which table.Data months is missing some ID.newID value. For each months in table.Data all the ID.newID value should be present. I would like to know for which months they are missing and which ID.newID is missing.

Comment: I understand now. You want the find the missing months, but you are trying to pull data that doesn't exist on `table` at all. You can probably solve this with just SQL, but it'll become too complicated, it'll be easier to solve with PHP (assuming this is under a LAMP environment).

Comment: This can be easily achieved in SQL, no need to script it in PHP or some other client script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only need the missing `ID` records that have a correlated `Month`, this is a simple *Non-Correlated* sub-query scenario.

> In SQL a *Non-Correlated* sub-query can be modeled either using a `NOT EXISTS` expression in the `WHERE` clause, or you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and only include the *NULL* results for the columns in the joined table, as this would indicate the records where no match was found

This query in only complicated by the fact that you want to evaluate the `MONTH` component of the date, not the explicit date value. SQL gives use all the necessary tools for this, we can even format the output that you desire:

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(CONCAT(m.year,'-',m.month,'-01') as DateTime), '%b-%y') as Data, i.Id as newId
FROM (
  SELECT YEAR(Data) AS Year, MONTH(Data) AS month
  FROM `table`
  GROUP BY YEAR(Data), MONTH(Data)
) m
CROSS JOIN `ID` i
LEFT OUTER JOIN `table` t ON YEAR(t.Data) = m.year AND MONTH(t.Data) = m.month AND t.newId = i.Id
WHERE t.Data IS NULL
ORDER BY m.Year DESC, m.month DESC
```

Have a look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72af42/2

---

> Choosing between `WHERE NOT EXISTS` AND `LEFT OUTER JOIN` can affect performance slightly, but the affect will depend on your query, your RDBMS and the available indexes. I *personally* use the `JOIN` syntax first because IMO it is simpler to maintain, but you use your own discretion.
>
> There is a lot of talk at least in MS SQL that `NOT EXISTS` should be faster than `JOIN` but if performance is an issue you for this specific query you should look at storing the `year` and `month` columns as persisted values so that they can be indexed and to reduce the function evaluatations.because it will evaluate less lookups.
>
> - [Best practice between using LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/121034/75699)
> - [SQL performance on LEFT OUTER JOIN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6777910/1690217)
> - [MySQL: NOT EXISTS vs LEFT OUTER JOIN…IS NULL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61521/75699)

For a comparison, this is the equivalent `WHERE NOT EXISTS` query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72af42/5

```sql
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(CONCAT(m.year,'-',m.month,'-01') as DateTime), '%b-%y') as Data, i.Id as newId
FROM (
  SELECT YEAR(Data) AS Year, MONTH(Data) AS month
  FROM `table`
  GROUP BY YEAR(Data), MONTH(Data)
) m
CROSS JOIN `ID` i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `table` t 
  WHERE YEAR(t.Data) = m.year 
    AND MONTH(t.Data) = m.month 
    AND t.newId = i.Id
)
ORDER BY m.Year DESC, m.month DESC
```

---

### How to Optimise using Persisted Values?

If we pre-evaluate the `YEAR()` and `MONTH()` and store the results in the table directly, then the query speed will improve but we can also add indexes to super-charge it.

> Consider the over all PROs and CONs before going this far...
>
> - Do you really need this level of optimisation?
> - How often is the query going to be executed?
> - Can you change the application logic to use a more appropriate `WHERE` clause to restrict the scope of the data instead?

#### Materialized Views

One solution to this is to create and manage a materialised view. This is a DW technique that effectively allows you to define a view but have it executed on a regular basis and stored into it's own table space.

> A materialised View does not optimise your query, but it allows you to execute complex and long-running query once, so that the results can be queried directly like a normal table, without having to re-evaluate column expressions.

Your data and the type of query looks like a good candidate for materialized view because it is querying historical data that has a zero or very low rate of change, only new rows are updated, and we probably do not care for the current month results. In this case if you end up running the query many times, and the result is staying more or less constant, then why not run the query as a process, say every month and store the results in a purpose built table, then your application can query that table frequently with lightning fast results.

> MySQL does not support Materialized Views, but you can replicate the concept as explained above in your application logic, some other RDBMS provide this OOTB, its the concept that should be considered.

#### Computed Columns

You could just add the extra columns to your table and maintain these columns from the user/application logic, but that is not very reliable, unless you trust your application developers and the app is the only process that will be updating this table.

Computed columns are perfect for reliability in this scenario, but they will only help us with performance if you can persist the value to the column store. (the default state of a computed column is that the expression will be evaluated at execution time, which offers little benefit over the current query)

> Again this is where MySQL will let you down, many other RDBMS offer simpler ways to do this, [you need MySQL v5.7 for this to work](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)
>
> ```
> ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `year` GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(Data)) STORED;
> ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `month` GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MONTH(Data)) STORED;
> ```

#### Trigger

Your other option is to add the columns, and then use triggers to maintain the values, MySQL doesn't make this easy, but it can work

1. Add the columns to your table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `table` ADD (`year` int NULL);
   ALTER TABLE `table` ADD (`month` int NULL);
   ```
2. Create Triggers to manage the values in these columns so the user cannot override them:

   ```
   DELIMITER $$

   CREATE TRIGGER persist_index_values_insert
     BEFORE INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     SET new.year= YEAR(new.Data);
     SET new.month = MONTH(NEW.Data);
   END$$

   CREATE TRIGGER persist_index_values_update
   BEFORE UPDATE ON `table` FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     SET NEW.year = YEAR(NEW.Data);
     SET NEW.month = MONTH(NEW.Data);
   END$$
   ```

   DELIMITER ;
3. Simpler Query:

   ```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CAST(CONCAT(m.year,'-',m.month,'-01') as DateTime), '%b-%y') as Data, i.Id as newId
    FROM (
      SELECT `year`, `month`
      FROM `table`
      GROUP BY `year`, `month`
    ) m
    CROSS JOIN `ID` i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `table` t ON t.year = m.year AND t.month = m.month AND t.newId = i.Id
    WHERE t.Data IS NULL
    ORDER BY m.Year DESC, m.month DESC
   ```
4. Indexes can now be applied as needed, you should consult your query execution plans for guidance, but I would suggest you need one index for `year` and `month` and `newId` as a minimum:

   ```
     CREATE INDEX IX_TABLE_YEAR_MONTH_NEWID ON `table` (`year`,`month`,'newId');
   ```

Comment: It's is perfect, it's working like a sharme. The only problem is that I have a lot of data and mysql goes in timeout so I need to put a "filter" in the first SELECT to limitate the data to be managed by the query

Comment: Yes, SQL 101 **always** include a  `WHERE` or `TOP` limiting criteria in production datasets. But you can persist the _Year_ and _Month_ (or a combination of them) lookups into the `table` schema and apply indexes on those columns to improve performance. A persisted computed column would help here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48099455/1690217

Comment: sorry but I don't understand how to use persist Year and Month into talbe and how to adapt the code above code, could you help me ?

Comment: @LucaFolin what version of MySQL do you have?

Comment: @LucaFolin I added some detail on optimisation, but it's really a general concept outside of the scope of this particular post.